# Ruby on Rails using Data Table based on Rails Cast #340

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datatable, datatables

I have been following the railscast 340 tutorial, but I have not been able to render the data via js. The table is empty to me and the data does not show me, what could be doing wrong?

this is my clientesdatatable.rb

```
class ClientesDatatable
delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :number_to_currency, to: :@views

def initialize(view)
  @view = view
end

def as_json(options = {})
  {
    sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
    iTotalRecords: Cliente.count,
    iTotalDisplayRecords: Clientes.total_entries,
    aaData: data
  }
end
def data
  clientes.map do |cliente|
    [
      h(cliente.IdCli),
      h(cliente.IdCli),
      h(cliente.IdCli),
      h(cliente.IdCli),
      h(cliente.IdCli),
      h(cliente.IdCli),
      h(cliente.IdCli),
      h(cliente.IdCli),
      h(cliente.IdCli),
      h(cliente.IdCli),
      h(cliente.IdCli),
      h(cliente.IdCli)
    ]
  end
end

def clientes
  @clientes ||= fetch_clientes
end

def fetch_clientes
  clientes = Cliente.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
  clientes = clientes.page(page).per_page(per_page)
  if params[:sSearch].present?
    clientes = clientes.where("IdCli like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%"))
end
clientes
end



def page
  [:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
end

def per_page
  params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10

end



def sort_column
    columns = %w[IdCli IdCli IdCli IdCli IdCli IdCli IdCli IdCli IdCli IdCli IdCli IdCli IdCli]
#   columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i] <-- used in video
    columns[params[:order]["0"]["column"].to_i] #<-- works in Rails 4
end

def sort_direction
    params[:order]["0"]["dir"] #<-- works in Rails 4
#   params[:sSortDir_0] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc" <-- used in video
end


end
```

my clienteController

```
  def index

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: ClientesDatatable.new(view_context)}
  end
```

my client.coffe

```
jQuery ->
  $('#clientes').DataTable
    "Processing": true
    "ServerSide": true
    "Ajax": {
      url: $('#clientes').data('source'),
      type: "get"
    }
```

and my table:

```
<table id="clientes" class="display" data-source="<%=clientes_url(format: "json")%>"><!--el id clientes es de datatables referenciado en clientes.coffe y display class es una clase de datatables-->
  <thead>

    <tr><!--active es para sombrear la fila-->
      <th>Clave</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Nombre Corto</th>
      <th>Dirección</th>
      <th>Colonia</th>
      <th>Credito</th>
      <th>DiasCredito</th>
      <th>LimiteCredito</th>
      <th>Saldo</th>
      <th>Ruta</th>
      <th>Promociones</th>
      <th>Acción</th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody id="container_clientes">
</tbody>


</table>
```

in localhost:3000/cliente.json  I get this error:

Module::DelegationError in ClientesController#index

```
ClientesDatatable#params delegated to @views.params, but @views is nil: #<ClientesDatatable:0x84da9678 @view=#<#<Class:0x84dc0b20>:0x84db4528 @_routes=nil, @_config={}, @view_renderer=#<ActionView::Renderer:0x84db45dc @lookup_context=#<ActionView::LookupContext:0x84f4b4f4 @details_key=nil, @details={:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder, :haml]}, @skip_default_locale=false, @cache=true, @prefixes=["clientes", "application"], @rendered_format=:json, @view_paths=#<ActionView::PathSet:0x84f4b490 @paths=[#<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x85542bb4 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x85542ba0 @data=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache::SmallCache:0x85542b8c @backend={}, @default_proc=#<Proc:0x8275fa30@/home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:49 (lambda)>>>, @path="/home/luis/sites/AdvanceControldatatablejs2017/app/views">,
```

Comment: try the url directly from the browser to see if the issue is in the server side or client side. like localhost:3000/cliente.json

Comment: @sethi thanks for answer. I tried localhost:3000/clientes.json  but I throw the following error: uninitialized constant ClientesController::ClientesDatatable (in this line:    format.json { render json: ClientesDatatable.new(view_context)})

Comment: where is this file clientesdatatable.rb ?? make sure that its loaded.

Comment: @sethi Is in the folder named "datatable" inside the app folder. I already saw my error and is that the name of the file had written badly, placing an s of more clients_datatables.rb now I get another error, check my post update please

Comment: ClientesDatatable#params delegated but @views is nil:

Comment: Was it just a spelling mistake of views/view?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution thanks to the instructions made by this gem https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails/wiki/Part-1----The-Installation